# Scala Class Loader for Avro Tools Run Method Written in Java

Tags: java, scala, avro, avro-tools

I'm having some difficulty in determining the means for loading an "Avro Tools" class and its `run` method. The issue is somewhere between java and scala interfacing and class loading methods. Due to the fact that avro is used elsewhere in a Spark app with a different version for loading data files, I need to be able to treat this particular method as a siloed call to another version of avro-tools.

The following is my code:

```
package samples

import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, InputStream}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MySpecTest extends Specification {
  "Class Loader" should {
    "load an implement a class" in {

      var classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(
        Array(new java.io.File("./avro-tools-1.9.1.jar").toURI.toURL),
        this.getClass.getClassLoader)

      var clazzDFRT = classLoader.loadClass("org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileRepairTool")

      val objDFRT = clazzDFRT.getConstructor().newInstance()
      val toolCmdArgsAsJava = List("-o", "all", "questionable.avro", "fixed.avro").asJava
      val stdin : InputStream = null
      val out: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
      val stdout = new PrintStream(out) // added stdout in edit#1

      val err = System.err
      val toolClassArgsAsJava = List(stdin, stdout, // changed out to stdout in edit#1 
          err, toolCmdArgsAsJava).asJava 

      //  parameterTypes: Class[_] *
      //  public int run( InputStream stdin, PrintStream out, PrintStream err, List<String> args)

      val paramClasses: Array[Class[_]] = Array(classOf[InputStream], classOf[PrintStream], classOf[PrintStream], classOf[java.util.List[_]])

      val method = clazzDFRT.getMethod("run",  paramClasses : _*)

      // the following produces wrong number of arguments exception
      method.invoke(objDFRT.asInstanceOf[Object], toolClassArgsAsJava)

      // sidebar: is this the end result for the Unit test - want out str with summary
      out.toString("UTF-8").contains("File Summary")
    }
  }
}
```

I seem to have some issue in the invoke method part, but maybe the whole solution is a little off - I need to be able to invoke the method as well as load, instantiate or ...

How can I fix this to run the entire code segment (and repair a broken avro)?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the exact nature of the problem since you didn't include the exception or stack trace. I am not sure why you are loading the avro tools dynamically instead of including the jar statically as part of your build.

```
//  public int run( InputStream stdin, PrintStream out, PrintStream err, List<String> args)
val method = clazzDFRT.getMethod("run",  Class[_] : _*)
```

You are not specifying the parameters correctly.

method.invoke(objDFRT.asInstanceOf[Object], toolClassArgsAsJava)

```
val params: Array[Class[_]] = Array(classOf[InputStream], classOf[PrintStream], classOf[PrintStream], classOf[java.util.List[_]])
val method = clazzDFRT.getMethod("run",  params : _*)
```

or

```
val method = clazzDFRT.getMethod("run", classOf[InputStream], classOf[PrintStream], classOf[PrintStream], classOf[java.util.List[_]])
```

To fix the invoke, you cannot pass the parameters in a list. The invoke method takes variable arguments, you need to pass these in directly.

```
method.invoke(objDFRT.asInstanceOf[Object], stdin, stdout, stderr, toolCmdArgsAsJava)
```

or

```
method.invoke(objDFRT.asInstanceOf[Object], Array(stdin, stdout, stderr, toolCmdArgsAsJava): _*)
```

Notice the second option uses an `Array` not a `List`.

I suggest you read up on the documentation for using var args in Java and Scala
* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html
* http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/varargs.html

Comment: Thx. That helps me get past the part about loading the method. I'm stuck on the invoking part now. Sidebar: I'm loading the jar as another code part uses the older version of the avro libraries and I need the tool from the newer version.

Comment: Updated to talk answer invoke